# How do we test for an optional hash field using Test2::V0

Tags: perl, testing

I am trying to work out how to test for an optional hash field using [Test2::V0](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test2::V0). I currently have the following:

```
use 5.016;
use Test2::V0;

subtest 'optional fields in a hash' => sub {
    my $check = hash {
        field foo => qr/^[0-9]+$/;
        field bar => qr/^[a-zA-Z]+$/; # this field is optional
    };

    like(
        { foo => 1 },
        $check,
        'should pass when optional field is omitted',
    );

    like(
        { foo => 2, bar => 'a' },
        $check,
        'should pass when optional field is provided',
    );
};

done_testing;
```

Now if I drop the check for the optional field:

```
my $check = hash {
    field foo => qr/^[0-9]+$/;
    # field bar => qr/^[a-zA-Z]+$/; # this field is optional
};
```

the test will pass. But I want to test the value when it's there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [`Test2::Tools::Compare`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test2::Tools::Compare)'s `in_set` - the following works for me. Don't forget to test failures as well `:-)`

```
use warnings;
use 5.016;
use Test2::V0;

subtest 'optional fields in a hash' => sub {
    my $check = hash {
        field foo => qr/^[0-9]+$/;
        field bar => in_set( DNE(), qr/^[a-zA-Z]+$/ );
    };
    like( { foo => 1 }, $check,
        'should pass when optional field is omitted' );
    like( { foo => 2, bar => 'a' }, $check,
        'should pass when optional field is provided' );
    unlike( { foo => 2, bar => undef }, $check,
        'should fail when optional field is provided with no value' );
    unlike( { foo => 2, bar => '+' }, $check,
        'should fail when optional field is provided with bad value' );
};

done_testing;
```

Comment: I am the inventor/maintainer of Test2, I approve this answer as a correct one.